# Cloning listview rows

Tags: c#, listview

Really frustrated with this listview methods and procedures. All I am trying to do is clone items one-by-one from one listview to another listview and I can't get it to work dispite all my investigations and attempts.

The target lisview is not displaying any items

Could someone please show me where I am going wrong.

This is what I have got so far:-

Thanks in advance

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
  foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){
     if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())) {
         var index = item.Index; 
         listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
         MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items[index].ToString());
         CopySelectedItems(listView1, listView2);
         count++;
     }
  }
}


 private static void CopySelectedItems(ListView source, ListView target){
        foreach (ListViewItem item in source.SelectedItems){
            target.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        }
 }
```

Comment: what is wrong ????

Comment: The target lisview is not displaying any items... thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: is soruce list box support multiselect ????

Comment: Soruce and target ListView MultiSelect is set to False

Comment: what is type of object you are binding with list box ...if you are not binding any type only string than let me know...also give me details of the object you are binding with your list box

Comment: Not sure ... can I post/email the full procedure for you to see ?

Comment: ok..post it i have look

Comment: is it possible you could send me a email address as posting this 30 line procedure is not possible.

Comment: pranayamr@gmail.com ...i will come back to you asap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160620/discussion-between-bob-g-and-pranay-rana).

Comment: Does the destination listview have the columns set up like the source? If Not, I don't think you'll actually see the items in the second listview. I just tried your code and removed the columns from the second listview and received a scrollbar telling me my data did something but without the columns defined, I could not see that information. (as a test, copy your source listview (call this listview3) and change your code to use listview3 as the destination and see if that changes things).

Comment: Ok.... I made a copy from the working ListView1 and called the copy ListView2, so I was assuming the columns along with settings would be the same... I will try your instructions..

Comment: I tried your instructions, but nothing happen... same blank screen. I noticed however, in the copy versions (ListView2 and ListView3) the columns headers are also missing. I am not sure if I am onto anything. Again... I would assume if the original headers are showing in ListView1 then they should at lease showup in ListView2 and ListView3.

Comment: The destination must be set up with the same columns as the source. For example if your source has 5 columns, then create 5 columns for the destination. I'm assuming the columns in the source are being generated from a datasource so copying it would have no affect as those columns aren't generated until run-time.. Just as a test, make sure you add to your destination list, the proper number of columns and then work from there.

Comment: Basically... what your are saying is, although I copied ListView2 from ListView1, I still have to setup columns and headers in ListView2 ?

Comment: Charles.... Cracked it! I went through my code, copied the lines that made up the header and columns for ListView1 then applied them to ListView2... did a bit of tweaking here and there and guess what... everything worked. Thanks very much!